# row operations in matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, filtering

I got a matrix  which has `Error` and `Blank` inside. I have to replace `Error` with `Max - Min` of its row and replace `Blank` with mean of its row.

When I tried to do it, I couldn't do the `Max - Min` because of `Error` word in the row.

Could someone help?

```
mat = RandomReal[{0,2},{10,10}];

mat[[1,3]] = mat[[6,8]] = mat[[4,4]] = mat[[10,5]] = "Error";

mat[[2,8]] = mat[[5,3]] = mat[[4,7]] = mat[[8,7]] = "Blank";

mat//MatrixForm
```

Guys, little change, Blank should be mean of its column,..

Answer (score 6):

```
subs[mat_] :=(bl = Mean[Select[#, NumericQ]];
              er = Differences[MinMax[Select[#, NumericQ]]][[1]];
              # /. {"Blank" -> bl, "Error" -> er}) & /@ mat;

MatrixForm[subs[mat]]
```

Comment: You have typo. It is `Blank` not `Blanck` :)

Comment: Thanks @Nasser. For a moment I was worried that I might have done something right on the first attempt ;)

Comment: I recommend using `NumericQ` instead of `NumberQ`. `NumberQ` will not work with matrices that contain mathematical constants like `Pi`.

Answer (score 5):

Define helper function:

```
replaceErrorAndBlank[row_List] := Module[{
   numericEntries = Select[row, NumericQ],
   minMax,
   mean
},
   minMax = Subtract @@ Reverse[MinMax @ numericEntries];
   mean = Mean[numericEntries];
   Replace[row, {"Error" -> minMax, "Blank" -> mean}, {1}]
];
```

Map over the matrix:

```
replaceErrorAndBlank /@ mat // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 3):

Make data

```
mat = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {10, 10}];
mat[[1, 3]] = mat[[6, 8]] = mat[[4, 4]] = mat[[10, 5]] = "Error";
mat[[2, 8]] = mat[[5, 3]] = mat[[4, 7]] = mat[[8, 7]] = "Blank";
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Fix

```
err    = Position[mat, "Error"];
blank  = Position[mat, "Blank"];
tmp    = ReplacePart[mat, Join[err, blank] -> Nothing];

maxmin = (z = tmp[[First@#]];  Max[z] - Min[z]) & /@ err;
mean   = (z = tmp[[First@#]];  Mean[z])         & /@ blank;

ReplacePart[mat, Join[Thread[err -> maxmin], Thread[blank -> mean]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a more complex alternative, without defining auxiliary function:

```
((#[[2]] /. #[[1]]) & /@ 
 Transpose@{(Which[
     Cases[#, _String] == {"Error"}, 
     "Error" -> Abs@(Subtract @@ MinMax[Select[#, NumericQ]]), 
     Cases[#, _String] == {"Blank"}, 
     "Blank" -> Mean[Select[#, NumericQ]], 
     Cases[#, _String] == {"Error", "Blank"}, 
     {"Error" -> Abs@(Subtract @@ MinMax[Select[#, NumericQ]]), 
      "Blank" -> Mean[Select[#, NumericQ]]}, 
     Cases[#, "Error" || "Blank"] == {}, {}] & /@ mat), 
 mat}) // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use functions from [Function Composition & Operator Forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionCompositionAndOperatorForms.html) (e.g. [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) and [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html)) and functions from [Applying Functions to Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ApplyingFunctionsToLists.html) (e.g. [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html)
 and [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)) to directly replace.

With `mat` defined with `SeedRandom[123];` then

```
MapThread[
 #1 /. Thread[{"Error", "Blank"} -> #2] &,
 {
  mat,
  mat /. {"Error" | "Blank" -> Nothing} // 
   Map[Through@{First@*Differences@*MinMax, Mean}[#] &]
  }] // MatrixForm
```

gives

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think the special behaviors of `Query` are the way to go here.

Let's set up a new matrix like so:

```
newMat = mat /. {"Blank" -> Missing["Blank"], "Error" -> Missing["Error"]}
```

Make a processing function like so:

```
f[row_] := 
 row /.
   {Missing["Error"] :> First@Differences[Query[MinMax]@row], 
     Missing["Blank"] :> Query[Mean]@row}
```

and do

```
f /@ newMat
```